# How to count specific orders that were ordered after a specific initial order was placed by the same customer?

Tags: conditional-statements, expression, limit, percentage, spotfire

Using Spotfire Syntax, how can I count the number of orders purchased by the same customer id of a specific product after an initial product was purchased? example:

I need to know how many binders and Art were purchased after paper was ordered by the same customer. How many lead paper orders turned into binder orders, I need the count and then the percentage of binder orders were initial paper purchases and Percent of Art were initial paper purchases.

If((
[category]=”binders”) OR (([category]=”Art”) and (
Sum(If(([Category]=”paper”) and ([Order Date]<=Max([Order Date]) OVER (Intersect([Customer ID]))),1,0))>0)),
1,
0)

The flag works except it is still counting binders and art that were purchased before paper, I only want to count these items if they were purchased after paper and by the same customer.

[see example table click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fuuwc.png)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest this approach.

First define a [*Category_Type*] column that assigns 'A' to Paper, 'B' to Art and Binders and 'C' to the rest.
This makes it a bit easier and more transparent to define further if statements. I used A,B,C because I want to exploit the alphabetical order in the next column.

```
case  
when [Category]='Paper' then 'A' 
when ([Category]='Art') or ([Category]='Binders') then 'B'
else 'C'
end
```

Then define your target column (mimicking the logic in the example you show) as:

```
case  when ([Category_Type]='B') and (Min([Category_Type]) over (Intersect([Customer ID],AllPrevious([Order Date])))='A') then 1 
else 0 
end
```

Since we assigned A to Paper, the statement

```
Min([Category_Type]) over (Intersect([Customer ID],AllPrevious([Order Date])))='A'
```

should catch all events for the current customer in previous transactions when Paper was ordered. So if the current category is of type B and we had an A in the past, this counts as 1.